# how to toggle between roadmap view and satellite view(google maps)on click of a single button in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to toggle between the map views by clicking on a single button, by far i am able to view satellite view on click but i am not able to toggle it to roadmap view.

```
 <v-btn class="white" @click="selectMapType('satellite')" 
       :class="{
           'mob-map-types' : this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xs
              }" 
 >
                <b class="pa-2">S</b>    
</v-btn> 



    toggle: false



 selectMapType(value){
    this.toggle= !this.toggle;
       if(this.toggle){
           this.neeMap.map.setMapTypeId(value);
          }
         else{
          this.neeMap.map.setMapTypeId(this.mapTypeOptions.roadmap)
          }
            
   },
```

Please help me if there is any other way to do this or am i missing something. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You were very close but I don't know what you have stored inside `this.mapTypeOptions`. Despite that, this should work for you :

```js
<template>
  <v-btn
    class="white"
    @click="selectMapType()"
    :class="{
      'mob-map-types': this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xs,
    }"
  >
    <b class="pa-2">S</b>
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      toggle: false,
      selectMapType() {
        this.toggle = !this.toggle;
        this.neeMap.map.setMapTypeId(this.toggle ? "roadmap" : "satellite");
        // if you don't know what the "?" and ":" do, look up ternary operator ;)
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Make sure, when you initialize your map, to set the default `mapTypeId` to "satellite" :

```js
const mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  mapTypeId: 'satellite'
};
```